# Paste Image Data from Clipboard to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, copy-paste, clipboard

Is it possible to paste image data into Chrome to then view the image?

For example, I right click on an image on a webpage then click "Copy image."

With the image data on my clipboard, how can I paste it into a new Chrome tab? It would be like when you drag and drop an image file onto Chrome and it opens it. But instead of dragging and dropping an image file, I just want to paste image data from the clipboard to have Chrome open it.

Is that possible? Maybe by enabling a hidden Chrome option or by using an extension? Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you copy an image, and then open a Chrome page, you can paste the image into the page. I do this from time to time.  Have Clipboard open Chrome?  Not natively for sure. I have not seen an extension but there may be one.

Answer (score 0):

You can click "Paste & Go " on the hotbar, [Right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYDuz.png)

Comment: Not quite. That only works with image URLs, not actual image data. Try it by right-clicking some images on a page then doing "Copy image." You'll see you can't paste the image data. That only works if you copy image URLs.

Comment: @GTSJoe Did you copy it from MS paint or another painting program?